# Markdown lack of margin in sub-lists (<ul> and <ol>)

Tags: bug, design, markdown

The list of elements have the image removed by [*all.css*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/all.css?v=6747fd591ed9):

```
ol ul, ul ol, ul ul, ol ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This causes a strangeness in the text that should be separated, see how it works as expected:

> Hello world!
>
> - Foo
> - Bar
> - Baz
>
> End line

However this way the `End last item` is "glued" to the "Last sub-item":

> Hello world!
>
> - First item
> - Second item
> - Last item
>
>   1. First sub-item
>   2. Second sub-item
>   3. Last sub-item
>
>   End last item
>
> End line

Code:

```
Hello world!

- First item
- Second item
- Last item

  1. First sub-item
  1. Second sub-item
  1. Last sub-item

  End last item

End line
```

> Note: The `End last item` is part of `- Last item`

Comment: Sort-a-workaround: Insert a blank line between `1. Foo`  and `1. Bar`. That gives `Last Line` some vertical spacing. (But increases spacing between the two numbered list items.)

Comment: @Mat Thanks! It's work :)